# Strategy: How do I exchange data directly between JavaScript and Google App Engine DataStore

Tags: google-app-engine

I am somewhat new to Web development - specifically Google App Engine and JavaScript/HTML development, but I have an app deployed and working on Google App Engine and it is working ok.

I would like a user of my App to be able to store and retrieve a serialization of the app state in JSON using the GAE Datastore. (Note - This is only a user-initiated action - so channels seem to be overkill)

The examples provided by Google demonstrates one approach that allows the server-side Python implementation to do this.  Specifically https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/gettingstartedpython27/usingdatastore.  I have this working ok.

But this approach seems rather inelegant especially if as an "app" I want to store and retrieve serialized chunks of data somewhat asynchronously without reloading the page/app each time (again, this is only ever user-initiated).

I have not been able to find any high-level guidance on an approach to do that (assuming it is possible).

Any suggestions/links/examples would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you!

Jeff

Answer (score 1):

As with many things, this depends on your specific needs.  If you just want direct access to datastore storage, the [datastore is exposed as an independent service with an API](https://developers.google.com/datastore/).

If you instead want to assert logic over the usage and interact with your app in some fashion, you may also want to look at [Google Cloud Endpoints](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/endpoints/).  With an endpoints API, you gain a more structured API you can call directly from javascript, or generate client libraries to be consumed by other languages/platforms.